# Spring integration dsl: route by payload type

Tags: spring-integration

Given:

```
   return from(listenerContainer(connectionFactory, queue))
             .handle(Foo.class, new HandlerForFoo()).get();
}
```

how can I make it call HandlerForBar given the channel receives a payload of type Bar.class? I mean something like this:

```
      return from(listenerContainer(connectionFactory, queue))
             .handle(Bar.class, new HandlerForBar());
             .handle(Foo.class, new HandlerForFoo()).get();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. The flow definition assumes that the second `.handle()` follows after the first.

For your `payload type` purpose there is exactly a special Enterprise Integration Pattern - [Message Router](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageRouter.html).

The Spring Integration provides the particular implementation on the matter - [`PayloadTypeRouter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-payloadtyperouter).

With the Spring Integration Java DSL we can reach your requirements with something like this:

```
.<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m -> m
        .subFlowMapping(Bar.class, sf -> sf.handle(new HandlerForBar())
        .subFlowMapping(Foo.class, sf -> sf.handle(new HandlerForFoo())
```

Comment: The above code should either not be using `.getName()` or have `<Object, String>` instead of `<Object, Class<?>>` otherwise it will not compile